# Bind array to rows

Tags: sapui5

I have an ajax json response and I have managed to bind the values into columns but I need to bind the values into rows.

I tried using oTable.bindRows("/"), but this binds the values into columns.

As a sample array I have : ( this is a response from a service )

```
Info [3]
[0] Object
name: "name",
surname: "surn"
[1] Object
address: "address",
phone: "22",
key: "val"
key2: "val2"
[2] Object
info: "information",
system: "sys",
data:"data here"
```

And I need a table( or a list ):

```
Key      Value
name     name
surname  surn
phone    22
system   sys
info     information
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to convert your Array. Please check below running example.

```
 oData.forEach(function(data){
     var keys = Object.keys(data);
     keys.forEach(function(key){
         oData_new.push({'key':key,'value':data[key]});
         });
     });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>

<script>
  var oData = [{
      name: "name",
      surname: "surn"
    }, {
      address: "address",
      phone: "22",
      key: "val",
      key2: "val2"
    },
    {
      info: "information",
      system: "sys",
      data: "data here"
    }
  ];
  var oData_new = [];

  oData.forEach(function(data) {
    var keys = Object.keys(data);

    keys.forEach(function(key) {
      oData_new.push({
        'key': key,
        'value': data[key]
      });
    });
  });


  var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
  oModel.setData(oData_new);


  var aColumns = [
    new sap.m.Column({
      header: new sap.m.Label({
        text: "Key"
      })
    }),
    new sap.m.Column({
      header: new sap.m.Label({
        text: "Value"
      })
    })
  ];

  var oTable = new sap.m.Table({
    columns: aColumns
  });
  oTable.setModel(oModel);

  oTable.bindAggregation("items", {
    path: "/",
    template: new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
      cells: [
        new sap.m.Text({
          text: {
            path: 'key'
          }
        }),
        new sap.m.Text({
          text: {
            path: 'value',
          }
        })
      ]
    })
  });
  oTable.placeAt('content');
</script>

<body id="content" class="sapUiBody">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer ! I am getting oModel.forEach is not a function, and also not recognizing the model in the view... I am making an ajax call on a press event

Comment: Did you check the example? forEach is the method of Array which in your case should be "Info".

Comment: Yes, I fixed the forEach error but I dont know why it doesn't recognize the model in the view...

Comment: I can help with a concrete example with specific errors. Can you post it on JSBin?